# Не отображается горизонтальный ScrollBar у DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Программно прописываю у `DataGridView`, что должен быть и горизонтальный, и вертикальный `ScrollBar`. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Но горизонтальный на форме у `DataGridView` не отображается, не все ячейки строки видны. Не пойму почему.

Подскажите где ошибка или чего не хватает?

Код настройки и заполнения `DataGridView`:

```
public void CreateViewDatagridViewWithStringColumns(DataGridView dataGridView, List<Dictionary<string, string>> sourseList)
{  
            string[] masKeys = sourseList[0].Keys.ToArray();
  
            dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView.Columns.Clear();
            CreateColumnsDataGridViewString(dataGridView,sourseList[0].Keys.ToArray());
            dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> diction in sourseList)
            {
                dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True; //перенос по словам
                dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();//Create New Row


                foreach (string key in masKeys)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell newCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();//Create New Cell
                    newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);//Add Cell to Row
                    newRow.Cells[i].Value = diction[key];
                    if(diction[key].Contains("Нов. знач.:"))
                    newRow.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                }
                dataGridView.Rows.Add(newRow);//Add Row To Datagrid
            }
}

private void CreateColumnsDataGridViewString(DataGridView dataGridView, string[] nameColumns)
{
            foreach (string nameColumn in nameColumns)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
                column.HeaderText = nameColumn;
                column.Name = nameColumn;
                column.Frozen = true;
                column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
            }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в каком контейнере лежит dataGridView? Возможно он не влезает в контейнер

Comment: Просто на форме лежит

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае скриншот формы может помочь.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скрин

Comment: У самого верхнего DataGridView ничего специально не задавал, и там все нормально - оба скролбара отображаются

Comment: Все колонки в гриде стоят `column.Frozen = true;`, то есть они не должны смещаться при горизонтальном скроллинге - поэтому скроллить и нечего

Comment: Вы правы. Спасибо! Напишите свой ответ в ответах - я отмечу как решение